# BeautifulSoup can't find tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web-page to collect a list of Fortune 500 companies. However, when I run this code, BeautifulSoup can't find `<div class="rt-tr-group" role="rowgroup">` tags.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r'https://fortune.com/fortune500/2019/search/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

data = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'rt-tr-group'})
```

Instead, I just get an empty list. I've tried changing the parser but saw no results.

The tags exist and can be seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN4KE.png):

Comment: The element you're trying to find is dynamically generated. `requests.get` only returns the source of the webpage. In case of the source of the website in question, there are no elements with the class `rt-tr-group` here.

Answer (score 1):

Data is loading on that page using JS, after some time.
Using Selenium, you can wait for page to be loaded completely, or try to get data from Javascript.

P.S. You can check for XHR requests and try to get JSON instead, without parsing. [Here is one request](https://content.fortune.com/wp-json/irving/v1/data/franchise-search-results?list_id=2611932&token=Zm9ydHVuZTpCcHNyZmtNZCN5SndjWkkhNHFqMndEOTM=)

Comment: I'm very new to python and BeautifulSoup, do you know any sources that could help me understand what you're talking about?

Comment: You can `print(soup)` and check source code you get using requests.

Answer (score 0):

Content of your parsing page loading with JS, and you can get empty page with `requests.get`.