# Nested tags are not accessable with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, tags

i have been trying for a while to extract specific data from different websites using beautifulsoup, and it doesn't seem to work for deeply nested tags.
I have tried it like this:

```
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find(["g"], class_="highcharts-series-group")
```

I also tried navigating from a "high parent" tag, down to the nested tag which I want to access, but at some point the tags are not found anymore. This problem occurred on several websites.

I don't understand why I get an empty list or a "none" when I search for a tag with a specific ID or class, which for sure exists in the HTML data. My only guess is that the website is blocking this information.

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: First at all take a look into your soup - There is the truth.  Is your element in your soup? Also add the url and expected output to improve your question, please.

Comment: beautifulsoup doesn't care about "nestedness", if it's in the soup it finds. but i think we're in an xy problem here: g is an svg tag and by the class name it looks like some graph/plot. probably you don't really want the g tag (honestly no one wants to scrape that), just the data itself

Comment: From https://www.finanzen.net/devisen/kryptowaehrungen I want to get the data points from a graph and I can also see the data points in my browser via F12. I checked the soup, the part I am looking for is indeed not in there and I can see the previous and following tag, in between there is a part missing (<div class=highcharts-container). Also when I search for a data point in my soup there is no result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup can't find tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702092/beautifulsoup-cant-find-tag)

Comment: No, it is a similar problem but they have not found a solution.

Comment: the data appears to be at `https://www.finanzen.net/ajax/GetCryptoCompareChartSeries` with lists in the format `[timestamp, value]`. i can't help you more, my hardware says no